# Fabric: logout and then login as a new user

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I'm working on `fabfile` which configures `Ubuntu 16.04` server from scratch and deploy `Django` project.

First thing what it does is:

```
def create_user_and_set_sshkeyauth():
    # creates new sudoer user and set ssh authorized_keys

def do_stuff_as_new_user():
    # installs dependencies, sets database, deploys django
```

Workflow:

```
create_user_and_set_sshkeyauth()
# LOGOUT ROOT, LOGIN THE NEW USER
do_stuff_as_new_user()
```

So I want to logout from root account and login as the new created user and do stuff under this user. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `settings` context manager is the way to do it:

```
@roles('foo')
def whatever():
   create_user_and_set_sshkeyauth()

   with settings(user='otheruser'):

      do_stuff_as_new_user()
```